# how to make a new table from an existing table and add new column in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I want to Ask about spreadsheet or google-sheets formula. I have a data that looks like this:

```
   A       B           C          D
   ------------------------------------------------
1 | UserId  fruitType   media     PriceStatus
2 | 3       Apple       Bag       Paid
3 | 7       Banana      Bag       Paid
4 | 7       Apple       Bag       Paid
5 | 43      Banana      Bag       Paid
6 | 43      Apple       Bag       FREE
7 | 43      Apple       Cart      Credit
```

Note:

1. My data only consist of 2 type of fruit : **Apple** and **banana**
2. 2 type of media : **Bag** and **Cart**
3. 3 Type of PriceStatus : **Paid**, **Credit**, & **Free**

As you can see the column is the same as the one in spreadsheet that I give value **A-D** and the row as **1-7**, My plan is to make the sheets look like this:

```
UserId  Apple   Banana
3          1       0
7          1       1 
43         2       1
```

is it possible to make a new table like this in spreadsheet? I tried using `VLOOKUP` but still failed to implement it, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:D, "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: wow Thank you it works like charm when I try it, but can I ask one more think? instead of blank cell can we give it zero instead? so it easier to make a conditional if statement

Comment: sure, you can do: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY(A1:D, "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 1)*1, QUERY(A1:D, "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 1)))`